# jQuery function doesn't work in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have a jQuery function that is not working under Laravel and i think it just needs to be rewritten and declared differently.

This is the error that i get in browser:
[image: error]

Under normal environment with jQuery 2.2.3 it works just fine like in
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wxj147m2/)

and this is the source code:

```
// replace , with . and block writing letters
$.fn.ForceNumericOnly = function() {
        return this.each(function() {
      if($(this).data('forceNumericOnly')){ return; }
      $(this).data('forceNumericOnly', true);
            $(this).keydown(function(e) {
                if(e.keyCode==188 || e.keyCode==110 || e.keyCode==108){
                    e.preventDefault(); 
                    $(this).val($(this).val() + '.');
                }
                    var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
                    return (key == 8 || key == 9 || key == 46 || key == 110 || key == 188 || key == 190 || (key >= 35 && key <= 40) || (key >= 48 && key <= 57) || (key >= 96 && key <= 105));                
            });
        });
};

// execute function on element focus
$(document).on('focus', '.amount', function(){
    $(this).ForceNumericOnly();
});
```

More info:

[image: folder tree]

routes.php file

[image: routes.php]

This is app.blade.php layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Laravel</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-XdYbMnZ/QjLh6iI4ogqCTaIjrFk87ip+ekIjefZch0Y+PvJ8CDYtEs1ipDmPorQ+" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    {{-- <link href="{{ elixir('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"> --}}

    <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Lato';
        }

        .fa-btn {
            margin-right: 6px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body id="app-layout">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">

                <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <!-- Branding Image -->
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                    Secure
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
                <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    @if (Auth::guest())
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Home</a></li>
                    @elseif (!Auth::guest() && Auth::user()->isAdmin())
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ url('admin') }}">Admin</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ url('anfrage') }}">Anfrage</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ url('angebote') }}">Angebote</a></li>
                    @elseif (!Auth::guest() && Auth::user()->isAgentur())
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ url('angebotmachen') }}">Angebot machen</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ url('anfrage') }}">Anfrage</a></li>
                    @elseif (!Auth::guest() && Auth::user()->isEndkunde())
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ url('anfragestellen') }}">Anfrage stellen</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ url('angebote') }}">Angebote</a></li>
                    @endif
                </ul>

                <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <!-- Authentication Links -->
                    @if (Auth::guest())
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ url('rgagenturen') }}">Register Agenturen</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ url('rgendkunden') }}">Register Endkunden</a></li>
                    @else
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                                {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="{{ url('/logout') }}"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-out"></i>Logout</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    @endif
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    @yield('content')

    <!-- JavaScripts -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    {{-- <script src="{{ elixir('js/app.js') }}"></script> --}}
</body>
</html>
```

This is angebotmachen.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Angebot machen</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'agentur/angebotmachen', 'method' => 'POST' )) }}
<table id="t1">
    <tr>
        <th><button type="button" class="addRow">Personal hinzuf&uuml;gen</button></th>
        <th>Anzahl</th>
        <th>Preis pro Stunde</th>
        <th>Stunden</th>
        <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row0" class="item">
        <td>{{ Form::select('personal[]', array(
               'koeche' => 'K&ouml;che',
               'barkeeper' => 'Barkeeper',
               'garderobiere' => 'Garderobiere',
               'chauffeure' => 'Chauffeure',
               'oberkellner' => 'Oberkellner',
               'serviceleitung' => 'Serviceleitung',
               'hilfskoch' => 'Hilfskoch',
               'servicekraefte' => 'Servicekr&auml;fte',
               ), null, ['placeholder' => '--ausw&auml;hlen']) }}
       </td>
        <td><input name="anzahl[]" class="qnty amount" value="" type="number" min="0" step="1"></td>
        <td><input name="preisps[]" class="price amount" value=""></td>
        <td><input name="stunden[]" class="hours amount" value=""></td>
        <td><input name="total[]" class="total" value="" readonly="readonly" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<br />

<table id="t2">
  <tr>
    <th>Netto =<br></th>
    <th>{{ Form::text('netto', '', ['id' => 'netto', 'readonly' => 'readonly']) }}</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Steuer 19% =<br></td>
    <td>{{ Form::text('steuer', '', ['id' => 'steuer', 'readonly' => 'readonly']) }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Brutto =<br></td>
    <td>{{ Form::text('brutto', '', ['id' => 'brutto', 'readonly' => 'readonly']) }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
    <br>
  {{ Form::submit('Submit') }}
  {{ Form::reset('Reset') }}
  {{ Form::close() }}

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>  
// main function when page is opened
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // function for adding a new row
        var r = 0;
        $('.addRow').click(function () {
            r++;
            $('#t1').append('<tr id="row' + r + '" class="item"><td><select name="personal[]" class="select"><optgroup label="Personal"><option selected="true" disabled="true" style="display:none">--ausw&auml;hlen</option><option value="koeche">K&ouml;che</option><option value="barkeeper">Barkeeper</option><option value="garderobiere">Garderobiere</option><option value="chauffeure">Chauffeure</option><option value="oberkellner">Oberkellner</option><option value="serviceleitung">Serviceleitung</option><option value="hilfskoch">Hilfskoch</option><option value="servicekraefte">Servicekr&auml;fte</option></optgroup></select></td><td><input name="anzahl[]" class="qnty amount" value="" type="number" min="0" step="1"></td><td><input name="preisps[]" class="price amount" value=""></td><td><input name="stunden[]" class="hours amount" value=""></td><td><input name="total[]" class="total" value="" readonly="readonly"></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="' + r + '" class="btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
        });
        // remove row when X is clicked
        $(document).on("click", ".btn_remove", function () {
            var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
            $("#row" + button_id + '').remove();
        });

        // calculate everything
        $(document).on("keyup", ".amount", calcAll);

    });

    // function for calculating everything
    function calcAll(event) {
        // calculate total for one row
          $(".item").each(function () {
            var qnty = 1;
            var price = 1;
            var hours = 1;
            var total = 1;
            if (!isNaN(parseFloat($(this).find(".qnty").val()))) {
                qnty = parseFloat($(this).find(".qnty").val());
            }
            if (!isNaN(parseFloat($(this).find(".price").val()))) {
                price = parseFloat($(this).find(".price").val());
            }
            if (!isNaN(parseFloat($(this).find(".hours").val()))) {
                hours = parseFloat($(this).find(".hours").val());
            }
            total = qnty * price * hours;
            $(this).find(".total").val(total.toFixed(2));
        });


        // sum all totals
        var sum = 0;
        $(".total").each(function () {
            if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }
        });

        // show values in netto, steuer, brutto fields
        $("#netto").val(sum.toFixed(2));
        $("#steuer").val(parseFloat(sum * 0.19).toFixed(2));
        $("#brutto").val(parseFloat(sum + parseFloat(($("#steuer").val()))).toFixed(2));

    }

    // replace , with . and block writing letters
    $.fn.ForceNumericOnly = function() {
            return this.each(function() {
          if($(this).data('forceNumericOnly')){ return; }
          $(this).data('forceNumericOnly', true);
                $(this).keydown(function(e) {
                    if(e.keyCode==188 || e.keyCode==110 || e.keyCode==108){
                        e.preventDefault(); 
                        $(this).val($(this).val() + '.');
                    }
                        var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
                        return (key == 8 || key == 9 || key == 46 || key == 110 || key == 188 || key == 190 || (key >= 35 && key <= 40) || (key >= 48 && key <= 57) || (key >= 96 && key <= 105));                
                });
            });
    };
    // execute function on element focus
    $(document).on('focus', '.amount', function(){
        $(this).ForceNumericOnly();
    });

</script>
@endsection
```

Comment: Could you provide some more info such as how this is actually loaded into the view?

Comment: I have added more info to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're loading jQuery twice, which is causing conflicts/errors.

You're loading it first in `app.blade.php` just before your `</body>` tag, and again in `angebotmachen.blade.php`.

The two jQuery libraries are conflicting, which is causing your issue.

You also need to load the jQuery library before you use:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    // etc
});
```